# javascript functions execution. put a function over the onclick event does not work

Tags: javascript, function, execution

Why when I put my code in this way: (the code works perfectly)

```
<div onclick="lightOn()" class="start-button dropbtn collapsible">
  <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
    <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>
      <p class="start-button-text start dropbtn">START</p>
  </div>
</div>

<nav id="myDropdown" class="dropdown content">
  <div class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">MARCAS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">REVIEWS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">NOTICIAS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">PREMIOS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">GUIA DE COMPRA</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But when I put my code in this way: (the code doesn't work)

```
<nav id="myDropdown" class="dropdown content">
  <div class="nav-list">
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">MARCAS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">REVIEWS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">NOTICIAS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">PREMIOS</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-items">GUIA DE COMPRA</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div onclick="lightOn()" class="start-button dropbtn collapsible">
  <div class="start-button-push dropbtn">
    <div id="light" class="start-button-light dropbtn"></div>
      <p class="start-button-text start dropbtn">START</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why it does not work one way, but works the other way.

I left the script it the same for the 2 examples.

```
<script>
  function lightOn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('light');
    if (x.style.background !== 'gold') {
        x.style.background = 'gold';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "250px";

    } else {
        x.style.background = 'black';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "0";

      }
    }

  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }
</script>
```

please help me I need that when I push the button the navbar shows under the button like the secon example. but does not let me do in this way instead I have to put the button over but I don't want that

Comment: Instead of inserting your function on the element directly, why don't you just give your button an id and attach your handler: `document.getElementById('[your button id]').onclick = function() {.....}`?

Comment: I already try but dosn't work

Comment: Not sure about what is your expected behavior. You said "when I push the button the navbar shows under the button". Do you mean you want to show/hide the navbar when the button is pressed, and the location for displaying the navbar should be under the button?

Comment: yes i want that the navbar show/hide over the button but i cant put it over the button only let me show/hide if the nav is under

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're facing currently. But if your code is working fine when `<div>` is placed before `<nav>`, then the problem maybe due to the line `var content = this.nextElementSibling;`. Try replacing it with `var content = this.previousElementSibling;`. Or maybe you can post a minimal css here so that we can experience what you're facing.

Comment: yes give me a second im gonna put a snipe code please help me

Comment: Ray Chan thank you so much changing to this.previous work perfect hahahah im so happy thank so much bro you help me alot

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try put your script after dom is loaded:

//JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  function lightOn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('light');
    if (x.style.background !== 'gold') {
        x.style.background = 'gold';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "250px";

    } else {
        x.style.background = 'black';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "0";

      }
    }

  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }
});


//JS
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 

  function lightOn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('light');
    if (x.style.background !== 'gold') {
        x.style.background = 'gold';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "250px";

    } else {
        x.style.background = 'black';
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        // document.getElementById("myDropdown").style.width = "0";

      }
    }

  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    });
  }

 }, false);
```